# What does the controller icon in the top right corner mean in MGS 5 Phantom Pain (PS3)?

Tags: ps3, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've noticed that during the cutscenes in the Prologue part, sometimes a controller icon would pop up in the top-right corner of the screen. What does it mean? Is it to indicate that the cutscene is about to transition back to gameplay?

Sometimes I turn off the controller during cutscenes as MGS is notorious for having some fairly long/drawn out ones. Could it be that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Controller icon appears, it simply means you can affect the scene (usually by simply moving the camera).

In my experience, its a visual / aesthetic option only, and you should be perfectly fine to ignore your controller during these moments.

Comment: But I've noticed I've always been able to do it using the R2 button, is this somehow different (I recall it used to be triangle in earlier versions)?

Comment: @Nobilis I'm not sure I understand? What does the R2 button do in that context?

Comment: It zooms in and then you can fiddle about with the right stick. I believe you can do it in all cutscenes, not just the ones where the joystick is present.

Comment: Ah, yes. The "change view" button. I think I bound that to R1 on my controller. Zooming is all it does (that I know of), and is part of the larger experience of, "You can mess with the camera".

Comment: Right, I thought there were some more to it, since I believe you can always mess with the camera a little bit and wasn't sure what the controller indicated.

Comment: You've been able to zoom in on cut scenes for many games, so the R2 button is this game's implementation, whereas the control icon indicates you have more control of the cut scene (like the R1 in games like MGS3 where you go into first person perspective). As @SableDreamer said, it's a visual cue that you can do something if you want, but don't have to.